# AppEngine setup with custom domain + sub domains

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

I've purchased a domain name with GoDaddy and have some sub domains setup, ie:

**www.example.com**

**status.example.com**

**store.example.com**

I want to create three applications on AppEngine under a single account, ie:

**example.appspot.com**

**status.appspot.com**

**store.appspot.com**

I would like to point each domain to a different app, ie:

**www.example.com      -> example.appspot.com**

**status.example.com   -> status.appspot.com**

**store.example.com    -> store.appspot.com**

The question is, what do I need to do to set this up?

Do I sign up to google apps and add **example.com** as my domain, then somehow link this to my appengine account, will the subdomains be recognized as belonging to my account or do I have to do some extra work to set these up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup the domain with [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html) (free version is fine), then add each of your apps to the domain.  You can add the app from the domain management console dashboard (click "Add more services").  When you add an app to the domain you can set the URL in the domain's management console.

There is also a [how to](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/domain.html) in the App Engine docs, it explains how to initial the process from your App Engine admin console.  I prefer to just handle all of the steps from the domain's management console.